# AAPT2 link failed Crashlytics

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Updated to Android studio 3 and am now getting the following error

Error:/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/com_crashlytics_build_id.xml uncompiled XML file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Which version of AS 3 are you running?

Comment: Android Studio 3 - Canary 7

Comment: Gotcha, we don't currently test against Canary versions of AS, but will be testing as the releases are more stable.

Comment: This is happening because crashlytics add files to the merged directory, which now contains compiled resources (when AAPT2 is used). @MikeBonnell to fix this you will need to compile the resources before they're added to the merged directory.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska can you share how to "compile the resources before they're added to the merged directory" please?

Comment: It's probably something the crashlytics lib/plugin owners should do. They need to be compiled with AAPT2. See here for more info on AAPT2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082352/how-to-use-aapt2-where-is-the-documentation/47017486#47017486

Answer (score 16):

Try adding:

```
android.enableAapt2 = false
```

to your `gradle.properties` file.

This enabled me to continue building my project with Crashlytics 2.6.8 on Android Studio 3 beta2.