# AAPT ERROR: Invalid BCP 47 tag in directory name b+sr+latn_values

Tags: android, gradle, aapt, ietf-bcp-47

I am trying to run a command via `aapt` to test out the functionality.

```
./aapt package -f --no-crunch 
-M /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/androidTest/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml 
-I /home/username/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar 
-S /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/androidTest/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug/
```

But I get this weird error message.

```
invalid resource directory name: /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/androidTest/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug/ drawable-xhdpi-v4_abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png.flat
invalid resource directory name: /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/androidTest/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug/ drawable_abc_ic_go_search_api_material.xml.flat
invalid resource directory name: /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/androidTest/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug/ drawable-xxxhdpi-v4_abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png.flat
invalid resource directory name: /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/androidTest/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug/ color_abc_primary_text_material_light.xml.flat
invalid resource directory name: /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/androidTest/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug/ drawable-mdpi-v4_abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png.flat
ERROR: Invalid BCP 47 tag in directory name b+sr+latn_values
```

And so forth like this.

I am using Gradle 3.0.1 to build the project. What causes this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gradle 3.0.1` doesn't uses `aapt` it uses `aapt2` by default. The build process is different for both of these.More details in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082352/how-to-use-aapt2-where-is-the-document).

`aapt2` can be disabled my adding `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties` file.