# Trying to compile java source with javac: package R does not exist

Tags: java, android, javac

I get this error compiling java sources into classes using javac.

There's the only layout for `MainActivity` in the `res` folder, I generated `R.java` with `aapt2` and imported it.

I used the following to create `R.java`:

```
aapt2 link --manifest AndroidManifest.xml -I android.jar -R co/layout_activity_main.xml.flat --java
```

And here are the errors that I am getting.

```
javac it/dummy/MainActivity.java -cp knoxsdk.jar:android.jar:it/
it/dummy/MainActivity.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
import it.dummy.R;
               ^
  symbol:   class R
  location: package it.dummy
it/dummy/MainActivity.java:19: error: package R does not exist
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        ^
it/dummy/MainActivity.java:21: error: package R does not exist
        final Button activateBtn = findViewById(R.id.activateBtn);
                                                 ^
it/dummy/MainActivity.java:29: error: package R does not exist
        final Button installBtn = findViewById(R.id.installBtn);
                                                ^
it/dummy/MainActivity.java:37: error: package R does not exist
        final Button updateBtn = findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);
                                               ^
5 errors
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) - edited tag.  Q: Why the heck are you running aapt2 manualy?  If you 1) Created the project with Android Studio, 2) DELETE `import it.dummy.R;` from your .java source, then finally 3) build with Android Studio - does everything "just work"?

Comment: Your title and your question do not agree. Different error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that R.java is in it/dummy/ and that MainActivity.java has `package it.dummy;`. What appears to be wrong is the classpath: should contain `'.'` instead of `'it/'`:

```
javac it/dummy/MainActivity.java -cp knoxsdk.jar:android.jar:.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compile your resource first in order to link them later with the `link` option as follows.

```
aapt2 compile -o co/res/ app/src/main/res/layout/layout_activity_main.xml
```

Also please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47017486/3145960) for other options.

Comment: You're correct: one needs to *COMPILE* the layout resource before one "links* it.  But it still begs the question: Q: *WHY NOT JUST USE ANDROID STUDIO*???  And related question: why put Android standard "R" in a non-standard place like "it.dummy"???

Comment: @paulsm4 LOL. I don't know, everybody has their own reasons.