# Found tag id where item is expected with aapt

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, android-resources, aapt

When I run this command :

```
"aapt.exe" package -f -m -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -I "android.jar" -S "\res" -J "\RJava" --auto-add-overlay
```

I receive the error : `Found tag id where item is expected`

It's this row in the `values.xml` that cause the problem :

```
<id name="view_tree_lifecycle_owner"/>
```

Note: with `aapt2.exe` it's work well, it's with `aapt.exe` that it's crash, but i need `aapt.exe` because I m building apk file

Comment: You can check the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91bce7cf-16f5-4037-902b-93309bb5d448/error-apt1000-found-tag-id-where-item-is-expected-apt1000-swlogandroid?forum=xamarinforms) and [this](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/found-tag-id-where-item-is-expected-error.127555/), it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated that

> with aapt2.exe it's work well, it's with aapt.exe that it's crash, but i need aapt.exe because I m building apk file.

[`aapt2`](https://developer.android.com/tools/aapt2) completely and fully-fledged replaced `aapt` in 2018. There is no good reason to stick with the old `aapt`. The Stackoverflow post on the [differences between `aapt` and `aapt2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082352/how-to-use-aapt2-where-is-the-documentation#47017486) can serve as an overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting your item definition to work with the older AAPT from:

```
<id name="view_tree_lifecycle_owner"/>
```

to

```
<item type="id" name="view_tree_lifecycle_owner"/>
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id